# Why decimal conversion error occurs in paymentdetailview in django-oscar 0.6? and how to fix this error?

Tags: python, django

I am using django oscar 0.6,in `paymentdetailsview` I have return the total price of  order 
from  `get_order_totals(self, basket, shipping_method, **kwargs)`, with
this error also .

```
TypeError at /checkout/payment-details/
Cannot convert <oscar.core.prices.Price object at 0xb8e28ac> to Decimal
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/payment-details/
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
Cannot convert <oscar.core.prices.Price object at 0xb8e28ac> to Decimal
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/decimal.py in __new__, line 658
Python Executable:  /home/stack/virtuals/stack/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.1
Python Path:    
['/home/stack/projects/stack',
 '/home/stack/virtuals/stack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-0.7.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/stack/virtuals/stack/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/stack/virtuals/stack/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/stack/virtuals/stack/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/stack/virtuals/stack/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/stack/virtuals/stack/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/stack/virtuals/stack/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/stack/virtuals/stack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
```

Comment: It would help to show the code where this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The get_order_totals method in oscar returns a Price object not a decimal value. You can access the dollar values like this:

```
total = get_order_totals(self, basket, shipping_method, **kwargs)
# order total including tax
total.incl_tax
# order total excluding tax
total.excl_tax
```